# High quality drag and drop cursor in WPF applications

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm just curious how I get Windows to use the high quality cursor when dragging and dropping in my WPF application.  What I mean by high quality is:

[image: High quality cursor.]

Rather than the regular arrow with a rectangle.  I tried using e.Effect but that didn't do anything...  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this just how it is in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use the cursor to do this, cursors are MOUSE POINTERS.

want you are looking for are Adorners

here is the doc on this subject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

and here is a very complete tuto on how to use drag & drop in WPF:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx

**Edit:** just to be precise: to achieve exactly what is shown on your image, you would in this case need an Adorner that follows the mouse + a blank cursor: `this.Cursor = Cursors.None;`

Comment: Thanks for the articles!  Sorry I forgot to mention that the I didn't actually want cursor to be missing, it just was removed from the image because of PrintScreen.